# Was my question really off topic?

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question

[I asked this question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/197833/find-recommended-system-requirements-for-all-owned-games) about trying to locate a summary of hardware requirements for all of my steam games. It eventually got closed as a recommendation question. I don't feel that I'm looking for any hardware or software recommendations and I attempted to edit it to clarify that. I also tried to reach out to the close voters for their reasoning as well with no feedback.

I'm new to this stack site but not to SE so I knew to go over the help center a few times before and after posting. Did I miss something that would make the question off topic?

Comment: You're running pretty close to the line of asking for recommendations, I feel.  You're trying to see if there's functionality in Steam to provide the minimum recommended system requirements.  Which, really, is just going to be the most taxing game's recommended system requirements, if we're going to be practical about it.  Find that game, and you have your answer.

Comment: I'm kinda on the fence on this. While this is somewhat a recommendation question, as you are asking for a resouce that has game system requirements, I feel like this is an invaluable question for people trying to find their game system requirements

Comment: @Frank Which is very true if you know which game is your most taxing. But like someone commented on the question, if you have 500 games that may not be easy to figure out.

Comment: @memescientist I considered that as well. But I guess I was thinking that as long as I worded the question well enough that it would elicit a good answer and not draw close votes either.

Comment: There had to have been a reason

Answer (score 5):

### IMO, No - It shouldn't have been closed. (It's not off-topic)

*I have no idea why it was voted to be closed for "recommendations", even though it's a question about finding information; basically what the developer recommends using.*

Your question was (in my words):

> **How do I find the recommended computer specifications for all the games I own?**
> *And then compile all of them into a single file for me to read to just to make sure it was compatable with my laptop.*

---

Following the FAQ:

> ... If your question generally covers things such as …
>
> - Gameplay strategies and tactics **No**
> - Puzzle solving or obstacle clearing **No**
> - Game mechanics and terminology **No**
> - Plot and characters in games **No**
> - Game-specific hardware and utilities **Yes!**

So, that's allowed. And the second bit:

> Please note, however, that site policies *prohibit* questions of the following types:
>
> - Game and Mod Development ([try the Game Development Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) instead) **No**
> - Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone **No**
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game) **No**
> - Shopping advice and recommendations **No**
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases **No**
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games. **No**

Also in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

It was completely on-topic. Your question was not a recommendation, it was:

> Can Steam do this thing? If so, how?

Questions about using Steam are completely on-topic here (it's gaming related).

Unfortunately, casually skimming the question and the title does give the impression that you're looking for a list online. Once one person doesn't bother reading the question before voting to close, it ends up on the close review queue, where people are even less likely to read it.